# Как спроектировать приложение?

Tags: база-данных, asp.net-mvc, архитектура

На asp.net mvc + mssql + ef пишу сайт, своего рода сборник кодексов (для себя в образовательных целях). Возникла проблема. Есть сущность **Статья** у которой есть номер. Например из ТК РФ:

> Цитата Статья 348.3. Медицинские осмотры (обследования) спортсменов

Вопрос: как хранить номер статьи в бд?

1. Пытался хранить как decimal(18,2), но тогда номер вида 348.10 будет равен 348.1 при форматирование т.к. отбрасываю конечные нули.
2. Хранить как просто строку можно, но сложнее будет сортировать и искать, ибо будет поиск по номеру статьи.
3. Даже думал хранить отдельно целую и десятичную часть, но тут еще больше проблем будет.

Сорри, если много букав, просто весь день уже голову ломаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Честно говоря, проблема кажется несколько надуманной. Храните в виде строки. Вы утверждаете, что возникнут проблемы производительности? Тогда результаты тестов с огрмоным падением этой самой производительности в студию. Скорее всего, падение производительности будет очевидным при очень большом объеме хранимых данных. Если же речь идет о таких сущностях, как статьи УК, то вряд ли вы будете оперировать очень большим их числом, а потому существенного падения производительности не получите. Иными словами, вы занимаетесь преждевременной оптимизацией, что является корнем всех бед

Comment: В вопросе указал, что делаю с образовательными целями, поэтому хочется всё сделать грамотно и красиво. Хранить номер статьи как число, мне кажется концептуально верным, но, видимо, действительно придется перейти к строковому типу. В принципе, в кодексах в среднем 500 статей * 10 кодексов ~5000 записей не должно быть слишком много.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вроде

```
00348.003.005.001
```

Сортировка будет по правилам, а перед выводом удалить лишние нули.

---

**Добавлено**
Не думал, что возникнут серьезные проблемы с пониманием предложенного мной варианта, поэтому поясню подробнее.  
Хранить мы будем не число, а строку в которой на каждый пункт/подпункт выделено фиксированное число знаков, это поможет сохранять естественный порядок при сортировке, потому что такие строки правильно упорядочены и будут возвращены именно в таком порядке после сортировки строк:

```
001.001
002.001
002.100
002.100.001
```

Помимо этого Вы можете хранить даже римские цифры и вообще любые упорядоченные наборы предварительно установив формат хранения.  
Например так Вы можете хранить римские цифры:

```
001.[[[012]]].001
```

Опять же- без лишних заморочек сохранилась естественная сортировка и для римских цифр.  
Единственное, что осталось сделать: изменять полученные данные при выводе их из базы.  
Например так можно убрать ведущие нули:

```
preg_replace("/(?<=\.|^)(?:0(?!\.|$))+/", "", $text);
```

Осталось заменить:

```
[[[012]]]
```

на:

```
XII
```

Ну а сколько фиксированных символов на хранение одного числа надо выделить- это уже смотря что надо хранить. Думаю, 4 символов хватит всем нуждающимся.

Comment: В столбце числового типа mssql у меня не сохраняет начальные нули.

Comment: @Vasya_P, я и не предлагал хранить числа, я имел ввиду привести строки к такому виду, чтобы сохранилась сортировка, которую Вы обозначили в вопросе как один из факторов, который нужен Вам в Вашем приложении.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы устроил небольшую денормализацию..
Хранил бы и так и так и эдак. Основными столбцами были бы статья (`int`), пункт (`int`) может еще подпункт. И несколько текстовых `varchar` генерирующихся триггером  при вставке или обновлении.
Мне было удобно..